# Mysterious white space outside of HTML flow?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div wrapper with four spans inside.

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div>
      <span>One</span>
      <span>Two</span>
      <span>Three</span>
      <span>Four</span>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

The div is positioned absolutely so that I can get it to touch the bottom of the screen, and text-align is justify so the spans inside are evenly spaced. This works fine until I try to make my spans height: 100%, then a mysterious white space appears outside of the actual  flow on the very bottom. I think this has something to do with my div:after psudo-element but I have absolutely no idea what's going on.

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(45, 45, 65);
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
}

div:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}

span {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 45);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

span:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Do I not understand how :after works, or is this some kind of a glitch? Where in the world is that white spacing coming from on the bottom?

Here's a reproduction of the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdpERR?editors=110

Comment: The reason is in `height: calc(100% - 20px);`, where 20px is not enaugh.

Comment: Why is it necessary to put 100% height on the span? If i delete this `height: calc(100% - 20px)` from `.link`. It looks fine to me, or is this not what you want?

Comment: @cybersoft Try changing it to -40px if you like. You'll see that you're incorrect; there's something invisible creating the gap.

Comment: @DavidDomain I appreciate the input but the question is clearly asking where the white space is coming from, not what a valid workaround would be

Comment: @WyattArent I have tried and I saw that link white block does not reach the bottom. So, it depends on browser and other stuff.. As a solution - try to use `box-sizing: border-box`, for my case it worked.

Comment: @cybersoft if you add box-sizing: border-box and then change the height to height: 100%; the issue persists. Please try again.

Comment: @WyattArent yes, now I see.

Comment: May be as workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/xmd4oyLz/

Comment: @cybersoft you removed the link-wrapper:after altogether so the spans are no longer evenly spaced. I'm greatful for the contribution but this isn't a workaround, it's a completely different end result

Comment: @WyattArent problem is in that `link-wrapper:after` pseudoclass. Why to not position second link to right of block? It will be evenly. Or use float property. Absolute positioned second link: http://jsfiddle.net/apddymvd/

Comment: @cybersoft And if I want 4 links evenly spaced on the same line? Five links? Dynamically without javascript? As I said to DavidDomain, I appreciate the input but the question is clearly asking for a explanation, not a workaround

Comment: @WyattArent and how do you use pseudoclass when links more than 2?

Comment: @cybersoft http://jsfiddle.net/zL5LptL4/2/ Resize the window large enough so they're all horizontally aligned. Right now I'm really just looking for someone to teach me, not for me to do to the teaching

Comment: @WyattArent cool... what I understand that I don't understand how links aligned with that pseudoclass :D

Comment: Since your `.link-wrapper` is positioned `absolute` it will actually not be part of the normal flow anymore. I know that this is not an explanation to the fact that your pseudo `:after` element creates a gap even though it's height is `0px`, but maybe that is just how pseudo elements are designed, at least whenever you add the `content` property. Which would explain why it increases the height of your `.link-wrapper` and will lead to an overflow of the document. Here https://jsfiddle.net/69et7stv/ you can see that the :after elem actually creates a gap just because it has a content prop.

Comment: @DavidDomain Close! A buddy just figured it out and explained exactly what's happening: "div:after { content: ''; } creates that layout bug, it inserts an empty line after the div. that gets a line-height without a reset-css." So it is in fact a layout bug. I've reported it to a few browser developers in case this is unexpected behavior. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yup, just figured this out as well, managed to reduce the height of the gap by adding `line-height:0` to the `.link-wrapper`, but that will still not solve the problem fully.

Comment: If you have a proper explanation and a solution that does not use `overflow:hidden` or and `box-sizing:border-box` you should post it, for anyone else you will stumble over this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simply add an   `overflow: hidden;` to the `main` or even the parent of the `main` should works.

Check the link
http://codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/yNpyLr?editors=110

Uncomment `overflow: hidden;`  or `box-sizing: border-box` then, the white space at the end of the web will be removed.

Also the box-sizing works ! i always have it with border-box so forgot it haha, and maybe its a better solution

Comment: Admittedly I rolled my eyes at this solution thinking it was a weak cover-up that I could instantly bypass using my middle mouse button/mouse wheel. This actually completely resolved the issue. What the hell? Either way I apologize for being quick to judge, and thank you very much for the solution.

If nobody can give an in-depth explanation on what's going on here I'll give you the answer

Comment: @Hector and Wyatt, i tried with overflow:hidden but still i can see big white gap then how it solved your issue?

Comment: @Leothelion I applied it to .link-wrapper however I'm also using Google Chrome so it may just be your browser? I'm wondering if this is some kind of formatting issue that every browser has

Comment: @wyatt i applied overflow:hidden in .link-wrapper class with your given code and i can see big white gap in chrome as well as ff too..

Comment: @Leothelion lol what in the hell, this is blowing my mind right now

Comment: @wyatt please check the comment of cybersoft with jsfiddle and tell me that is ok or not?

Comment: @wyatt sorry for confusing but i think m wrong..you are talking about white space under line one and link two or space between link one and link too?

Comment: @Leothelion Just the white space underneath it all. There's supposed to be a horizontal gap creating even distance between Link 1 and Link 2, but there's not supposed to be a fat white bar on the bottom

Comment: ohh i thought you are talking about white vertical space under the link 1 and 2..sorry for my bad..

Comment: @HéctorLeón yeah it works beautifully, Leo the lion just misunderstood which is okay. You've given the best answer so far but why there's an overflow is beyond me. It has to be some kind of formatting bug with the browsers. I'll let this question remain open for a little bit to see if anybody else has any clues, otherwise I'll submit it as a bug report to every browser developer I can think of

Comment: @HéctorLeón just please keep in mind that if you simply uncomment box-sizing: border-box then you must change the height to height: 100% otherwise the height of the span elements will be 20px too short. Then you'll see the issue is still produced

Comment: Right right, then @WyattArent i think the overflow with the box-sizing its the answer, i changed the color in the codepen example to red, now you can see it works

Comment: @HéctorLeón there is absolutely nothing underneath the red part that you're speaking of except a 20px gap for additional content. If you resize the link height from calc(100% - 20px) to height: 100% then the expected result would be that the red part touches the bottom, but this actually yields unexpected results of a white bar with absolutely no source. This has nothing to do with padding. For proof of this, change .link-wrapper bottom to bottom: 20px and link height to height: calc(100% + 20px) you will find the same error occurs with no cause (of course removing overflow: hidden)

Comment: @WyattArent maybe i understood wrong before, sorry.

Check the link now,   
codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/yNpyLr?editors=110
I applied the border-box because its better, but now i use 50vh instead of calc, so now you can change the padding value and still works, but obv with the overflow hidden, the after its ok, the problem with the space is with the absolute wrapper, but im not sure the reason. but at least i got a temporal solution man, really curious, now i have to work but lately i gonna try find out the problem.

Comment: @HéctorLeón yeah for sure, I really appreciate you Hector. I've opened a bugzilla ticket for it if you're interested in keeping track: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1177676

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to add `box-sizing:border-box`, becauase you have padding on those link elements.